# Why do AC SSRs have lower AC Voltage limits and what does this mean?

Tags: solid-state-relay

I want to use something like a Crydom D2450 SSR to switch AC current supplied by a variable transformer. This device is spec'd at 24-280VAC on the output. Why is there a lower output voltage limit (24VAC)? My device seems to work as low as a couple volts out of the transformer.

Comment: How do you spec "seems to"?

Comment: Because the output *must* be some amount of AC for the internal SCR's to disengage. It might also use a tiny part of that power internally, such that <24VAC cannot be guaranteed to operate correctly in all possible conditions. It might work for a few volts for you, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: Zero cross detection.

Comment: @Cary, it's polite to include a link to the datasheet. It saves us looking it up and ensures that we're all using the same one.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and comments. I apologize for not including a link to the datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is there a lower output voltage limit (24 VAC)?

Because some voltage is required to operate the triac.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPflBq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. An instant turn-on SSR features an opto-triac and a regular triac.*

TR1 requires some headroom to turn on. The SSR may work at lower voltages but the turn-on point will be late in the cycle because the voltage has to rise high enough for TR1 and TR2 to turn on.

[image]

*Figure 2. Resultant waveform if supply voltage is too low. Image mine.*

The same effect is seen at higher voltages but because the voltage is rising at a much faster rate the turn-on happens much earlier in the cycle and is barely noticible in the overall waveform.

[image]

*Figure 3. The zero-cross SSR features circuitry to suppress turn-on if the voltage has risen above a certain level. Source: [How opto-triacs and zero cross works](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/).*

You can read more in my article linked above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Don't forget to accept it if it answered your question. You can transfer acceptance to another answer if a better one shows up later.